# upgrading packages on 18.04 running on AWS ec2 instance results in error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

Attempting to upgrade packages on 18.04 running on an AWS ec2 instance and getting the following error.

```
The package linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1030 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I've tried `apt dist-upgrade` , `apt-get install --fix-missing` and `dpkg --configure -a`. All result in the same error above.The package `linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1030` doesn't appear to be listed in the [software packages for 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/devel/)

Thanks in advance for any help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out. Ran the following in order and resolved the problem.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1030
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade (this will throw an unmet dependencies error)
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```